# html css flex-box

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как расположить изображения ?

```
<ul class="ul_cake_block">
                    <li class="li_cake_block li_cake">
                        <div class="block_title_img">
                            <h5 class="title_img">Классические</h5>
                            <span class="sub_title_img">24 вида</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="link_img link_classic_cake">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li_cake_block">
                        <div class="block_title_img">
                            <h5 class="title_img">Муссовые</h5>
                            <span class="sub_title_img">12 видов</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="link_img link_mus_cake">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li_cake_block">
                        <div class="block_title_img">
                            <h5 class="title_img">Свадебные</h5>
                            <span class="sub_title_img">20 видов</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="link_img link_wedding_cake">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li_cake_block">
                        <div class="block_title_img">
                            <h5 class="title_img">Мужчинам</h5>
                            <span class="sub_title_img">12 видов</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="link_img link_mans_cake">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li_cake_block li_cake">
                        <div class="block_title_img">
                            <h5 class="title_img">Женщинам</h5>
                            <span class="sub_title_img">16 видов</span>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="link_img link_female_cake">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li_cake_block">
                        <div class="block_title_img">
                            <h5 class="title_img">Детские</h5>
                            <span class="sub_title_img">18 видов</span>
                        </div> 
                        <a href="#" class="link_img link_kids_cake">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

[image: Так должно быть]

Comment: Можно код и больше описания пж.

Comment: А как их надо расположить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите как расположить изображения

Не очень понятно, речь идет о расположении элементов в сетке или об изображениях на фоне элементов.

Просто через тег `<img>` можно расположить. А название и ссылку через абсолютное позиционирование

Результат:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.right-col {
  flex-basis: 35%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      <h3>Классические</h3>
      <p>24 вида</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/166/536/354" width="" height="">
    <a href="">Смотреть</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Классические</h3>
        <p>24 вида</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/166/536/354" width="" height="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Классические</h3>
        <p>24 вида</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/166/536/354" width="" height="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Comment: @Эрик, если ответ помог, можете пометить его решением. Скриншот галочки отметки: http://bit.ly/2Hss3VA